# Worksheet ranges and line breaks

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble to populate a very large amount of specific cells with zeros. It seems that it only works if the block of cells A1:B1 is alone, as in `Range("A1:B1")`. Any help? Thank you in advance.

```
Sub zeroes()

   Dim rng, t As Range
   Dim z As Integer

   z = 0

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

        Set rng = Range("A1:B1, C2:E2, F3:G3, H5:I5" _
                      & ",K11:M11, N1:O1, P6:Q6" _
                      & ",W4:Y4, Z7:AA7")
    For Each t In rng
        If t.Value = vbNullString Then t.Value = z
    Next

End Sub
```

**EDIT 1**

> ```
> Sub zeroes()
>
>    Dim rng As Range
>    Dim t as Range
>    Dim z As Integer
>
>
> Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
>
>      Set t = Union([FO11:FR11], [FO26:FR26], [FO40:FR40], [FO54:FR54], [FO68:FR68], [FO82:FR82], [FO96:FR96], [FO110:FR110], [GE11:GH11], [GE26:GH26], [GE40:GH40], [GE54:GH54], [GE68:GH68], [GE82:GH82], [GE96:GH96], [GE110:GH110], [GU11:GX11], [GU26:GX26], [GU40:GX40], [GU54:GX54], [GU68:GX68], [GU82:GX82], [GU96:GX96], [GU110:GX110], _
>                    [HK11:HN11], [HK26:HN26], [HK40:HN40], [HK54:HN54], [HK68:HN68], [HK82:HN82], [HK96:HN96], [HK110:HN110], [IA11:ID11], [IA26:ID26], [IA40:ID40], [IA54:ID54], [IA68:ID68], [IA82:ID82], [IA96:ID96], [IA110:ID110], [IQ11:IT11], [IQ26:IT26], [IQ40:IT40], [IQ54:IT54], [IQ68:IT68], [IQ82:IT82], [IQ96:IT96], [IQ110:IT110], _
>                    [JG11:JJ11], [JG26:JJ26], [JG40:JJ40], [JG54:JJ54], [JG68:JJ68], [JG82:JJ82], [JG96:JJ96], [JG110:JJ110], [JW11:JZ11], [JW26:JZ26], [JW40:JZ40], [JW54:JZ54], [JW68:JZ68], [JW82:JZ82], [JW96:JZ96], [JW110:JZ110], [KM11:KP11], [KM26:KP26], [KM40:KP40], [KM54:KP54], [KM68:KP68], [KM82:KP82], [KM96:KP96], [KM110:KP110], _
>                    [LC11:LF11], [LC26:LF26], [LC40:LF40], [LC54:LF54], [LC68:LF68], [LC82:LF82], [LC96:LF96], [LC110:LF110], [LS11:LV11], [LS26:LV26], [LS40:LV40], [LS54:LV54], [LS68:LV68], [LS82:LV82], [LS96:LV96], [LS110:LV110], [MI11:ML11], [MI26:ML26], [MI40:ML40], [MI54:ML54], [MI68:ML68], [MI82:ML82], [MI96:ML96], [MI110:ML110], _
>                    [MY11:NB11], [MY26:NB26], [MY40:NB40], [MY54:NB54], [MY68:NB68], [MY82:NB82], [MY96:NB96], [MY110:NB110], [NO11:NR11], [NO26:NR26], [NO40:NR40], [NO54:NR54], [NO68:NR68], [NO82:NR82], [NO96:NR96], [NO110:NR110], [OE11:OH11], [OE26:OH26], [OE40:OH40], [OE54:OH54], [OE68:OH68], [OE82:OH82], [OE96:OH96], [OE110:OH110], _
>                    [OU11:OX11], [OU26:OX26], [OU40:OX40], [OU54:OX54], [OU68:OX68], [OU82:OX82], [OU96:OX96], [OU110:OX110], [PK11:PN11], [PK26:PN26], [PK40:PN40], [PK54:PN54], [PK68:PN68], [PK82:PN82], [PK96:PN96], [PK110:PN110], [QA11:QD11], [QA26:QD26], [QA40:QD40], [QA54:QD54], [QA68:QD68], [QA82:QD82], [QA96:QD96], [QA110:QD110], _
>                    [QQ11:QT11], [QQ26:QT26], [QQ40:QT40], [QQ54:QT54], [QQ68:QT68], [QQ82:QT82], [QQ96:QT96], [QQ110:QT110], [RG11:RJ11], [RG26:RJ26], [RG40:RJ40], [RG54:RJ54], [RG68:RJ68], [RG82:RJ82], [RG96:RJ96], [RG110:RJ110], [RW11:RZ11], [RW26:RZ26], [RW40:RZ40], [RW54:RZ54], [RW68:RZ68], [RW82:RZ82], [RW96:RZ96], [RW110:RZ110], _
>                    [SM11:SP11], [SM26:SP26], [SM40:SP40], [SM54:SP54], [SM68:SP68], [SM82:SP82], [SM96:SP96], [SM110:SP110], [TC11:TF11], [TC26:TF26], [TC40:TF40], [TC54:TF54], [TC68:TF68], [TC82:TF82], [TC96:TF96], [TC110:TF110], [TS11:TV11], [TS26:TV26], [TS40:TV40], [TS54:TV54], [TS68:TV68], [TS82:TV82], [TS96:TV96], [TS110:TV110], _
>                    [UI11:UL11], [UI26:UL26], [UI40:UL40], [UI54:UL54], [UI68:UL68], [UI82:UL82], [UI96:UL96], [UI110:UL110], [UY11:VB11], [UY26:VB26], [UY40:VB40], [UY54:VB54], [UY68:VB68], [UY82:VB82], [UY96:VB96], [UY110:VB110], [VO11:VR11], [VO26:VR26], [VO40:VR40], [VO54:VR54], [VO68:VR68], [VO82:VR82], [VO96:VR96], [VO110:VR110], _
>                    [WE11:WH11], [WE26:WH26], [WE40:WH40], [WE54:WH54], [WE68:WH68], [WE82:WH82], [WE96:WH96], [WE110:WH110], [WU11:WX11], [WU26:WX26], [WU40:WX40], [WU54:WX54], [WU68:WX68], [WU82:WX82], [WU96:WX96], [WU110:WX110], [XK11:XN11], [XK26:XN26], [XK40:XN40], [XK54:XN54], [XK68:XN68], [XK82:XN82], [XK96:XN96], [XK110:XN110], _
>                    [YA11:YD11], [YA26:YD26], [YA40:YD40], [YA54:YD54], [YA68:YD68], [YA82:YD82], [YA96:YD96], [YA110:YD110], [YQ11:YT11], [YQ26:YT26], [YQ40:YT40], [YQ54:YT54], [YQ68:YT68], [YQ82:YT82], [YQ96:YT96], [YQ110:YT110], [ZG11:ZJ11], [ZG26:ZJ26], [ZG40:ZJ40], [ZG54:ZJ54], [ZG68:ZJ68], [ZG82:ZJ82], [ZG96:ZJ96], [ZG110:ZJ110], _
>                    [ZW11:ZZ11], [ZW26:ZZ26], [ZW40:ZZ40], [ZW54:ZZ54], [ZW68:ZZ68], [ZW82:ZZ82], [ZW96:ZZ96], [ZW110:ZZ110], [AAM11:AAP11], [AAM26:AAP26], [AAM40:AAP40], [AAM54:AAP54], [AAM68:AAP68], [AAM82:AAP82], [AAM96:AAP96], [AAM110:AAP110])
>
> For Each t In rng
>     If t.Value = vbNullString Then t.Value = z
> Next
> End sub
> ```

And now the error ... ***"Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"***

Comment: it looks like you want to set multiple ranges into `rng` am i right ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @LuizVaughan My answer had some inconsistent behavior  so I deleted it.  Use `MsgBox TypeName(Rng)` to test the variable declaration.  Ranges and object are initiated as nothing.  So if the Msgbox say `Nothing` then it's a range.  If it says `Missing` then it is a unassigned Variant Type.

Comment: Its `Set rng = Union(...)` but not `Set t = Union(...)`. `t` is your iterating variable that loops through `rng`. So it should not be assigned anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub zeroes()

    'need "As" for each declaration separated by comma. 
    'In "Dim rng, t As Range", rng will be declared as variant. But it wouldn't be a problem because it still works.
    Dim rng As Range, t As Range
    Dim z As Integer

    z = 0

    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

    'the syntax for Range() is Range(TopLeftCellAddress or FirstCellAddress, BottomRightCellAddress or LastCellAddress).

    'note: [A1:B1] is just another way of writing Range("A1:B1")
    Set rng = Union([A1:B1], [C2:E2], [F3:G3], [H5:I5], [K11:M11], [N1:O1], [P6:Q6], [W4:Y4], [Z7:AA7])


    For Each t In rng
        If t.Value = vbNullString Then t.Value = z
    Next

End Sub
```

HTH

---

Lets introduce another function `Intersect` into the macro.

```
Sub Sample_Union_and_Intersect()
    Dim wantedRows As Range
    Dim wantedCols As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim t As Range
    Dim i As Variant
    dim z as interger
    z=0

    'set initial wanted row
    Set wantedRows = [11:11]
    'Collect remaining wanted rows
    For Each i In Array(26, 40, 54, 68, 82, 96, 110)
        Set wantedRows = Union(wantedRows, Cells(i, 1).EntireRow)
    Next i
    Debug.Print wantedRows.Address

    'set initial wanter column
    Set wantedCols = [FO:FO]
    'Collect remaining wanted columns
    For Each i In Array("FR", "HK", "HN", "JG", "JJ")
        Set wantedCols = Union(wantedCols, Cells(1, i).EntireColumn)
    Next i
    Debug.Print wantedCols.Address

    'Intersect "wantedRows" and "wantedCols" to yield the wanted intersections.
    Set rng = Intersect(wantedRows, wantedCols)
    Debug.Print rng.Address

    For Each t In rng
        If t.Value = vbNullString Then t.Value = z
    Next


End Sub
```

FYI, `debug.print` prints out debug message in the "Immediate" window. If you don't see the Immediate window, just press `Ctrl+G` and the window will turn on.

Comment: It works if I keep all the blocks in a single line without line brakes. However, the line is too long. I must split it. If I do (see Edit 1 above), I get an error.

Comment: @LuizVaughan, i added a new function `Intersect` into your macro. I saw a pattern in the range you want. The error you got is just invalild use of `t`. `t` should not be assigned anything, instead do `set rng = Union(...)`. But see my answer above, it will makes your life easier.